# How to design a Spring MVC REST service?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I want the client and server application to talk to each other using REST services. I have been trying to design this using Spring MVC. I am looking for something like this:

1. Client does a POST rest service call `saveEmployee(employeeDTO, companyDTO)`
2. Server has a similar POST method in its controller `saveEmployee(employeeDTO, companyDTO)`

Can this be done using Spring MVC?

Comment: Here looks like a good example: http://www.stupidjavatricks.com/?p=54

Comment: @bwobbones, you should convert your comment in an answer ;)

Comment: @RC, didn't want to claim someone else's work...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. Here's a simple example (with Spring annotations) of a RESTful Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/someresource")
public class SomeController
{
    @Autowired SomeService someService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getResource(Model model, @PathVariable Integer id)
    {
        //get resource via someService and return to view
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveResource(Model model, SomeResource someREsource)
    {
        //store resource via someService and return to view
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String modifyResource(Model model, @PathVariable Integer id, SomeResource someResource)
    {
        //update resource with given identifier and given data via someService and return to view
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public String deleteResource(Model model, @PathVariable Integer id)
    {
        //delete resource with given identifier via someService and return to view
    }
}
```

Note that there are multiple ways of handling the incoming data from http-request (@RequestParam, @RequestBody, automatic mapping of post-parameters to a bean etc.). For longer and probably better explanations and tutorials, try googling for something like 'rest spring mvc' (without quotes).

Usually the clientside (browser) -stuff is done with JavaScript and AJAX, I'm a server-backend programmer and don't know lots about JavaScript, but there are lots of libraries available to help with it, for example see [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

See also:
[REST in Spring 3 MVC](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/)

Comment: I don't understand why you named the store/update/delete methods `getResource`.

Comment: Perils of copy-paste... didn't even notice it myself, I'll correct it. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  Rest is very easy to implement using spring MVC.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveEmploee.do",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void saveEmployee(@RequestBody Class myclass){
    //saving class.
    //your class should be sent as JSON and will be deserialized  by jackson
    //bean which should be present in your Spring xml.      
}
```

Comment: Can I have multiple @RequestBody arguments?

Comment: No. How would this make sense in a REST-Request?