# Spring MVC Support Ajax the way Rails Do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I started with Spring and Spring ROO as job switched with no past experience in Java Development. From last 1.5 year experience doing development in Ruby on Rails. So my new company want me to work with Spring and Spring ROO no Grails/Groovy:(. As no past experience in JAVA DEVELOPMENT struggling a lot with understanding of configuration of XML and Annotation support. Although i covered basics of but Now i was looking to find a way that Spring have such support of Ajax call CRUD operations of entities or Javascript call to execute script which i get as result of remote true URL click. As Rails framework (rails.js).

Hopefuly the person who work with ROR and Spring ROO may be best person to answer my question. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you give a step by step explanation what are you trying to create. By looking at the bulk format of your text it seems you didn't put enough effort in the writing of this questions, let alone something else. Ask properly, format and someone will answer if the question is clear and concise.

Answer (score 1):

To implement CRUD operations, I may suggest you to use REST service. It is easy to create with Spring MVC.

[Spring blog](http://blog.springsource.org/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/)

[Good example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/wa-spring3webserv/index.html)

[Another fast example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841498/how-to-design-a-spring-mvc-rest-service)

And ofcourse [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch18s02.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is copied part of my previous answer :

My advice to you would be to download the spring source(eclipse like IDE) :

http://www.springsource.org/springsource-tool-suite-download

After downloading it you can simply go to `File > New > Spring Template Project > Spring MVC project`

After you're done with creating project, the working template project(structured project, example controller file, example view, pom.xml etc.) will be created for you. You can just build it and deploy it to tomcat or whatever.

Btw. check this out :

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/MasteringSpringMVC3.pdf?raw=true

It is enough to get you started well off with Spring MVC.

Comment: Am asking for Ajax supportive URL and Forms the way Rails provide

Answer (score 0):

I once had the same problem to you (I used to develope Groovy/Grails, then switch to Spring MVC). Unfortunately, I don't think there's an easy way to make what you ask in Spring. Spring doesn't have much productivity-enhanced functions,but it enables flexibility instead.

In short, you will be able to do Ajax, but with a lot more manual configuration (pure html/javascript-[jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) and java code) - like in Vacuum answer.

[Jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) might be the best solution you can find though it only help you send the the CRUD requests to server side. You must write java code at server to process those requests.